# Postgres INNER JOIN same table failing on CartoDB

Tags: postgresql, join, cartodb

I have a table with data which looks like this

```
+----+------+-------+
| cp | year | count |
+----+------+-------+
| 1  | 2000 | 10000 |
| 1  | 2001 | 9000  |
| 1  | 2002 | 9500  |
| 2  | 2000 | 8000  |
| 2  | 2001 | 7500  |
| 2  | 2002 | 7000  |
+----+------+-------+
```

Every cp is guaranteed to have the same number of years. What I want is the percentage change between the current year and a reference year. So I'm after this:

```
+----+------+-------+-----------+--------------+
| cp | year | count | since2000 | since2000pct |
+----+------+-------+-----------+--------------+
| 1  | 2000 | 10000 | 0         | 0            |
| 1  | 2001 | 9000  | -1000     | -0.1         |
| 1  | 2002 | 9500  | -500      | -0.05        |
| 2  | 2000 | 20000 | 0         | 0            |
| 2  | 2001 | 16000 | -4000     | -0.2         |
| 2  | 2002 | 21000 | 1000      | 0.05         |
+----+------+-------+-----------+--------------+
```

It's been awhile since I've done much with SQL, but this looks like a pretty straightforward inner join. All I should need is the year 2000 count repeated for every row, and the rest is just math. I got it working using SQLFiddler:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/81a94/1/0

```
SELECT
*
FROM traffic_counts as s1
INNER JOIN
(SELECT cp, count AS count2000 FROM traffic_counts WHERE year = 2000) s2
ON s1.cp = s2.cp;
```

But when I try to run this on CartoDB (PostgreSQL 9.3.4) I'm getting an error saying that cp is ambiguous. (Fiddler has no problem…) I even tried aliasing the table to s3 inside the subselect and fully qualifying the first "cp", but the error was the same.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Well, it sounds like this is specific to CartoDB, so without access to that product, I doubt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may be that you have multiple columns of the same name in the result (2x `cp`). When using `SELECT *` you would return both.

The simple fix for the query at hand would be `USING` in the join clause, which only keeps *one instance* of the joined column in the result (and seems smarter in this particular case anyway):

```
SELECT *
FROM   traffic_counts s1
JOIN  (SELECT cp, count AS count2000 FROM traffic_counts WHERE year = 2000) s2 USING (cp);
```

Updated [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/81a94/4).

BTW, SQL Fiddle itself was updated only recently to allow such ambiguity. Until some months ago it also raised an error for queries with duplicate names in the result. Quite a few clients cannot cope with that.

Comment: USING was the SQL command I didn't know. Thanks very much for the super quick and clear explanation!

Comment: @NickK9: `USING` is not exactly a "command", [just a clause for join conditions in any `FROM` list](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM).